# Tkinter name error: "tk" Name is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

I am learning how to use Tkinter and I am receiving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hetparikh/PycharmProjects/BudCalculator/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tkinter import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    root = Tk()
NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined
```

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
theLabel = Label(root, text="This is too easy!")
theLabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that code... There was indentation before `from tkinter import *` in your original question, is it in your code ? It should not.

Comment: please show first 10 lines of file `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py`

Comment: The indentation is not there in the code. @Dionys

Comment: Thanks, it would have raised a syntax error anyways.

Comment: The file `tkinter/__init__.py` is part of the Python distribution, and should NOT contain the line `root = Tk()` as your traceback claims.  It looks like you've somehow overwritten this file with your own script.

Comment: How would I fix this @jasonharper

Comment: Reinstall Python 3.8 to fix it.

Comment: It worked for me. nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try instead:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text="This is too easy!")
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
theLabel = tk.Label(root, text="This is too easy!")
theLabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

this should work

Comment: `Label` should be `tk.Label`.